# Fetching Data From Server Using iOS Device in React Native

Tags: react-native, fetch, expo

I have just started learning React Native and development for mobile devices. One of the things I've tried is using fetch API to get data from http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
The App.js file is given below:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
    const [firstLoad, setLoad] = React.useState(true);
    const [data, upDateData] = React.useState([]);
    let isLoading = true;

    async function sampleFunc() {
        let response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
        let body = await response.json();
        upDateData(body);
    }

    if (firstLoad) {
        sampleFunc();
        setLoad(false);
    }

    if (data.length > 0) isLoading = false;

    const posts = data.map(post => (
        <div>
            <h1>{post.title}</h1>
            <p>{post.body}</p>
        </div>
    ));

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {isLoading ?
            <Text>Loading</Text> :
            <Text>{posts}</Text>
            }
        </View>
    );
}
```

Nothing fancy is going on here, just making an https request to the server to get posts. While the data is being transferred, the Loading label is being displayed, after that, all fetched posts are rendered on the page.

I am using Expo, and everything works fine when I run it in the browser, but when I scan the QR code, Expo app opens, the Loading message is displayed for a couple of seconds, and then the app crashes.

I may be doing something here that is typical of regular React and is not used in React Native. It is just strange that it would work on my computer and not the phone. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have text outside of `Text` components in react-native.

In your example, in the `post` function, you use the `h1` and `p` tags, which are not supported by react-native.

The fix here is to make sure that those texts are inside `Text` components, you can have styling set to those to make them look closer to what you want.

You can refer the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#limited-style-inheritance) on how to create custom styles.

```js
const posts = data.map(post => (
    <View>
        <Text>{post.title}</Text>
        <Text>{post.body}</Text>
    </View>
));
```

To debug similar issues in the future, you should be getting a red flashing screen with the exception. (Maybe it doesn't appear when running on Expo)

Comment: It is displaying data now, thank you so much!